# Optional relationship in Hierarchy

Tags: database-design

I have a hierarchy Area -> Zone -> Sector where Zone is optional i.e. a particular Sector may belong to an Area but the user may not want to break down at the Zone level. Additionally Sectors are not the same as Zones, they have different properties and Zones are effectively a collection of Sectors

Sectors have other entities related further down the hierarchy as well.

What I'd like to know is what's the best approach to modelling this in a database? I've done this before in a similar scenario and used a dummy Zone entity to then allow storage of the Sectors.

Anybody got any better ideas?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

If Areas and Zones are effectively similar enough in your application, you might want to consider using the same table for both (and use a flag column to distinguish which type a given row represents).  In this case, any Area/Zone could have a parent Area/Zone, and every Sector must have a parent Area/Zone.

For instance:

```
Table Container:
    Field container_id
    Field container_type
    Field parent_container_id (NULL)
Table Sector:
    Field parent_container_id
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you model it as an IS-A relationship? A zone is always an area and a sector is always an area.

There is an optional relationship between area and sector.

```
create  table dbo.area(
   area_id   numeric(8,0)  identity,
   parent_id   numeric(8,0)  not null, --whatever the parent table of area table is
   flag1   bit  not null,
   prop1 varchar(100) not null, -- many more props...
   constraint pk_0 primary key clustered ( area_id )
)

create  table dbo.zone(
   area_id   numeric(8,0)  not null,
   prop_z1   varchar(50)  null,

    constraint pk_1 primary key clustered ( area_id )
)

alter table dbo.zone
    add constraint fk_1 foreign key ( area_id )
    references dbo.area ( area_id )

-- same for sector

create  table dbo.sector(
   area_id   numeric(8,0)  not null,
   prop_s2   varchar(50)  null,

    constraint pk_2 primary key clustered ( area_id )
)

alter table dbo.sector
    add constraint fk_s1 foreign key ( area_id )
    references dbo.area ( area_id )
```

Its an odd design but hey you've asked for any alternative.

You can add one or more zone_id columns in the sector table, and if  you want to make it really hard for yourself, add  foreign key constraints to those.